# An interesting problem about multiplicity of roots of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Anyone know how to show the following interesting statement (maybe it is not true):

**Problem**: Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field with char $K=0$, and $f(X),g(X)\in K[X]$ be such that $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are relatively prime. For any $a\in K$, we define $h_a(X)=f(X)-ag(X)\in K[X]$. Then the discriminant $\Delta(a)$ of $h_a(X)$ is a **nonzero** polynomial of $a$.

Comment: Is it the **discriminant** you mean by any chance?

Comment: Consider the case $f(X)=X^3+bX^2+cX+d$ with $d\ne 0$ and $g(X)=X^3$.
Then $$\Delta(a)=b^2c^2-4(1-a)c^3-4b^3d+18(1-a)bcd-27(1-a)^2d^2\quad\text{if }a\ne 1.$$
But 
$\Delta(1)=c^2-4bd$, which differs from the above by a factor of $b^2$. Maybe you want to add the condition that $\deg g<\deg f$?

Comment: If the two polynomials are relatively prime over an algebraically closed field they have no roots in common. Do you see how this helps?

Comment: Yes, Caranti is right. It should be discriminant. I solved the problem. Just look at $H(X)=\frac{f(X)}{g(X)}$, so the zeros of $h_a(X)$ is the same as the zeros of $H(X)$. Notice that any multiplicity(means at least two) roots of $f(X)-ag(X)$ must be zeros of $f'(X)g(X)-f(X)g'(X)$.

Comment: To [BenjaLim](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/38268/benjalim), for example, let $f(X)=X^2$, $g(X)=X^2$, for any $a\in K$, we have $h_a(X)=(1-a)X^2$, then $\Delta(a)=0$ for all $a\in K$.

Comment: Quick comment: As stated, the problem is false. If $k$ has characteristic $p$, and $h(x)$ is a polynomial of the form $\sum a_k x^{kp}$, then $\Delta(h)=0$. So, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both polynomials in $x^p$, then $\Delta(f-ga)=0$. But this is the only exception (and Mingfeng Zhao's comment 2 before this one sketches a correct proof.)